# zend_gdata: Get google calendar if already logged in an application

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, zend-gdata, yii-extensions

I have created one application in YiiFramework which has two functionalities.

```
1. Login to google
```

For login to google, I have followed the tutorial on below website.

Tutorial : https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth
Tutorial Demo : http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo/login

```
2  Get calendar using Zend_Gdata Library
```

Tutorial : http://www.bcits.co.in/googlecalendar/index.php/site/install
Tutorial Demo : http://www.bcits.co.in/googlecalendar/index.php/site/page?view=about

[1st Step] I get successfully login to my application using yii-eauth. 
[2nd Step] when I need to use calendar, I am giving hard coded gmail Id and password.

I am accessing calendar in this way.

```
  <?php 
     $user = 'your gmail username';
     $pass ='your gmail password';
     Yii::app()->CALENDAR->login($user, $pass);
  ?>
```

login() in googlecalendar.php file.

```
 public function login($user, $pass) {

    $service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);// It uses hard-coded gmail/password to get login again
    $calenderlist = $this->outputCalendarList($client);
    $events = $this->outputCalendar($client);
    $calendardate = $this->outputCalendarByDateRange($client, $startDate = '2011-05-01', $endDate = '2011-06-01');
     .........
  }
```

Does Zend_Gdata library contain any function which automatically gets calendar of current user without again logging in(hard-coded here).

Stuck with this. Appreciate helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, `Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin` sets some parameters for `$client` which is the object returned.  See the following excerpt from that function:

```
if ($loginToken || $loginCaptcha) {
    if ($loginToken && $loginCaptcha) {
        $client->setParameterPost('logintoken', (string) $loginToken);
        $client->setParameterPost('logincaptcha', (string) $loginCaptcha);
    } else {
        require_once 'Zend/Gdata/App/AuthException.php';
        throw new Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException(
            'Please provide both a token ID and a user\'s response ' .
            'to the CAPTCHA challenge.');
    }
}
```

What you could do is store that token or that `$client` object (which is an instance of `Zend_Gdata_HttpClient`).  Pretty much all of the Zend_Gdata components accept a `$client` argument.

Check out the `__construct()` method for `Zend_Gdata_Calendar`:

So anyway, you would want something similar to this logic (sorry I'm not familiar with Yii):

```
$client = Yii::app()->getClient();
if (!$client) {
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
    Yii::app()->setClient($client);
}
```

Of course, *you* would have to then define that `getClient()` method somehow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);  would be the same as before. I dont want to pass username and password in getHttpClient(). hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: You need to **store** the `$client` from where you _originally_ login and and _get_ it here.  The `if` is a just-in-case sort of thing.  Get it?

Comment: ohhhh.. yes i get something now..need to work hard upon it :) ..thanks @mmmshuddup